# More efficient approach for Android stopwatch code?

Tags: java, android, timer, stopwatch

I'm a newbie to Android app development, so I know I'm probably making things way too complicated.

The code below works as expected (after many hours!!!), but I'm curious whether I'm handling the implementation of the two threads correctly? Like I said it runs at least, but I'm not sure if it's all necessary.

PS: Bonus points for showing me the formula to convert centiseconds into h:m:s:c so that I don't have to use that horrible String length solution I found lol! [EDIT ... see below, I found the answer to this part]

```
package com.test.advancedtimer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String time;   //Clock's combined time
    String elapsedTime;    //Stopwatch elapsed time
    int stopwatchHour = 0;
    int stopwatchMin = 0;
    int stopwatchSec = 0;
    int stopwatchCentiSec = 0;
    int elapsedSeconds = 0;
    int elapsedCentiseconds = 0;    //cumulative Centiseconds elapsed since starting countdown

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        updateTime();

    }

    //First timer that updates the clock display once every second
    public void updateTime() {
        Timer clockTimer = new Timer();
        clockTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getTime();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_display);
                        timeTextView.setText(getTime());
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    //Accesses system time and concatenates it into 'time' String, then returns it.
    public String getTime() {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int AM_PM = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        String AMorPM = "";

        // Establishes two-digit format for clock time
        time = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour + ":";
        time += (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min + ":";
        time += (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;

        if (AM_PM == 0) {
            AMorPM = "AM";
        } else if (AM_PM == 1) {
            AMorPM = "PM";
        }

        time += " " + AMorPM;
        return time;
    }

// Second timer that triggers the stopwatch to increment by centiseconds (1/10th seconds)
    public void startTimer(View view) {
        Timer stopwatchTimer = new Timer();
        stopwatchTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.runningTimer);
                        timerTextView.setText(stopwatch());
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 0, 10);
    }

    // Returns the combined string for the stopwatch, counting in tenths of seconds.
    public String stopwatch() {

        elapsedSeconds = elapsedCentiseconds / 100; //Conversion to enable use of same formula above
        stopwatchHour = elapsedSeconds / 3600;
        stopwatchMin = (elapsedSeconds % 3600) / 60;
        stopwatchSec = elapsedSeconds % 60;

        //Formats stopwatch to two digits per time unit.
        elapsedTime = (stopwatchHour < 10 ? "0" : "") + stopwatchHour + ":";
        elapsedTime += (stopwatchMin < 10 ? "0" : "") + stopwatchMin + ":";
        elapsedTime += (stopwatchSec < 10 ? "0" : "") + stopwatchSec + ":";

        //Grabs last two digits of total centiseconds for centisecond component.
      String centiSeconds = String.valueOf(elapsedCentiseconds);
        if (centiSeconds.length() >1) {
            elapsedTime += centiSeconds.charAt(centiSeconds.length() - 2);
            elapsedTime += centiSeconds.charAt(centiSeconds.length() - 1);
        } else {
            elapsedTime += "0" + centiSeconds.charAt(centiSeconds.length() - 1);
        }

        elapsedCentiseconds++;
        return elapsedTime;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: I finally got the maths to work for the conversion from deciseconds (which I switched to because the 100th of seconds digit was moving too fast to be of any use):**

```
// Returns the combined string for the stopwatch, counting in tenths of seconds.
    public String stopwatch() {

        //elapsedSeconds = elapsedDeciseconds / 10; //Conversion to enable use of same formula above
        stopwatchHour = (elapsedDeciseconds % 2160000) / 36000;
        stopwatchMin = (elapsedDeciseconds % 36000) / 600;
        stopwatchSec = (elapsedDeciseconds % 600) / 10;
        stopwatchDeciseconds = elapsedDeciseconds % 10;

        //Formats stopwatch to two digits per time unit.
        elapsedTime = (stopwatchHour < 10 ? "0" : "") + stopwatchHour + ":";
        elapsedTime += (stopwatchMin < 10 ? "0" : "") + stopwatchMin + ":";
        elapsedTime += (stopwatchSec < 10 ? "0" : "") + stopwatchSec + ":";
        elapsedTime += stopwatchDeciseconds;

        elapsedDeciseconds++;
        return elapsedTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public long startTime = 0;
public void startTimer(View view) {
    Timer stopwatchTimer = new Timer();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    stopwatchTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.runningTimer);
                    timerTextView.setText(stopwatch());
                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 10);
}

// Returns the combined string for the stopwatch, counting in tenths of seconds.
public String stopwatch() {
    long nowTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long cast = nowTime - startTime;
    Date date = new Date(cast);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.S");
    return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Tiny Sunlight ... SimpleDateFormat definitely seems simple enough lol.

Comment: If you use this on a Device which Standard Timezone is not UTC, it will not work correctly.  You can add the Timezone by using this:
`sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`